# JsonConvert.PopulateObject set int properties to 0 if there is no value

Tags: c#, json.net

I try to populate an object from JSON with Newtonsoft.Json (v13) and some properties of this object are not required. I expect the not required properties stay "null" so when I serialize them back, they will be ignored with `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` and don't appeared in the JSON result. But when I populate my object the int properties not present in my JSON was set to 0 by default instead of null like other type value.

The jsonData.txt file content :

```
{
    "name": "name" 
}
```

The sample code :

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string prop1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int prop2 { get; set; }

    public Myclass(){}
}

string myClassJson = File.ReadAllText("jsonData.txt");

MyClass myClassObj = new MyClass();

JsonConvert.PopulateObject(myClassJson, myClassObj);

string jsonFromMyClassObjSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClassObj);
```

The jsonFromMyClassObjSerialized result :

```
{
    "name": "name", 
    "prop2": 0
}
```

Comment: `int` is a value type so cannot be null. You need to use `int?` (`Nullable<int>`).

Answer (score 1):

Need to change the value type `int` with the `Nullable<int>` type to keep the properties null with  `JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`